# Two JQuery functions for auto height on the same website

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question regarding using a function multiple times on the page I am trying to set a block auto height in dependence of screen resolution but I have 2 divs on different pages that need to be applied this function, it get applied only for one div for ex:

first tie I apply it to following selectors

```
   <script>

       $(function () {
           resize_main_pane();
           $(window).resize(resize_main_pane);
       });
       function resize_main_pane() {
           var offset = $('.pagina-servicii').offset(),
           remaining_height = parseInt($(window).height() - offset.top - 105);
           $('.pagina-servicii').height(remaining_height);
       }
    </script>
```

second time to the following:

```
   <script>

       $(function () {
           resize_main_pane();
           $(window).resize(resize_main_pane);
       });
       function resize_main_pane() {
           var offset = $('.another-selector').offset(),
           remaining_height = parseInt($(window).height() - offset.top - 283);
           $('.another-selector').height(remaining_height);
       }
    </script>
```

How can I combine them or use separately? I wonder if I need to use some no conflict setting?

Comment: Don't worry about putting things like "Thanks in advance" and "Hello" it clutters the question. Reward good answers with upvotes!

Comment: What are those numbers based on? Because it would be best if you could get those numbers via different means. These "magic numbers", as they're called, might need to vary, based on different browsers and resolutions.

Answer (score 1):

Loop all selected divs and apply height to them:

```
function resize_main_pane() {
    $.each($('#selector1, #selector2', function(){
        var offsetMinus = $(this).hasClass('bigOffset') ? 283 : 105;
        var offset = $(this).offset(),
        remaining_height = parseInt($(window).height() - offset.top - offsetMinus);
        $(this).height(remaining_height);
    });
}
```

Comment: unfortunately they have different offset.top  :(

Comment: @AndrewCeban Thats why you are looping them. Calculate for each element

Comment: they both should have different offset one 105 px another 283 px

Comment: @AndrewCeban i updated answer with conditional offset

Comment: hmm, unfortunately it doesn't work you can see live website  [link](http://santehmaster.mdigital.md)

Answer (score 0):

Put your selectors in an array and loop trough them with `each`.
The `$(this)` will be either of your class selectors and calculates the offset and height independently.

```
$(function () {
   resize_main_pane();
   $(window).resize(resize_main_pane);
   // If you want to trigger this function on document load you could replace the above line with:
   $(window).resize(resize_main_pane).trigger('resize');
});
function resize_main_pane() {
    $('.pagina-servicii, .another-selector').each(function(index) {
        var offset = $(this).offset(),
        remaining_height = parseInt($(window).height() - offset.top - [105,283][index]);
        $(this).height(remaining_height);
    });
}
```

Comment: I do not understand a little bit , for first selector .pagina-servicii offset.top - should be 105 px, but for second selector .another-selector offset.top should be 283px in your example it works but gives for both 283 px

Comment: Then you changed that after I gave you the answer. I have changed my answer.

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake in the selectors. Put a `.` instead of a `,`. Does it work now?

Comment: probably I should insert something like autoreinitialise, if I change browser size it works, do you know hot to set it to autoreinitialise? It takes fisrt option 105 px :(